# Convert HTML Table to Pandas Data Frame in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here i am trying to extract a table from a website as specified in Python code . i am able to get the HTML Table and further i am unable to convert to data frame using Python . Here is the code

```html
# import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify url
url = 'http://my-trade.in/'

# request html
page = requests.get(url)

# Parse html using BeautifulSoup, you can use a different parser like lxml if present
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl =soup.find("table",{"id":"MainContent_dataGridView1"})
```

[image: How to convert this HTML Format Table to Data Frame]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just Use pandas read_html function for that, and remember to convert the html you get to string else you will get some parsing error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://my-trade.in/'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table",{"id":"MainContent_dataGridView1"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
```

Comment: above code is working fine , i was looking for writing a for loop for every column and then further cbinding it . i usually code in R , Pardon me i am new to python.